# Photoshop Script Change Anti-Alias Setting of All Text Layers

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am new to using Photoshop scripting and I am trying to do the following:
1) Select all text layers in the document
2) Change the anti-alias method to "MAC" (this is a new setting in Photoshop which now supplements Crisp, Strong, Sharp and Smooth.

I can change all the text layers to one of those settings because they are in the Photoshop Javascript Guide. However, because the "MAC" and "MAC LCD" settings are new features, how do I select these?

```
#target photosohop
app.bringToFont();

function changeAntiAlias( el, setting ) {
    var method = setting;

    if(setting == "smooth") {
       method = AntiAlias.SMOOTH;
    }
    if(setting == "sharp"){
       method = AntiAlias.SHARP;
    }
    if(setting == "crisp"){
       method = AntiAlias.CRISP;    
    }
    el.textItem.antiAliasMethod = method;
}

function main(){

    if(!documents.length) return;

    // Remember the document
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    // Get total number of layers
    var layerNum = doc.layers.length;

    // Loop through layers
    // Change anti-aliasing depending if it is a text layer
    for(var i = 0; i < layerNum; i++){
        var layer = doc.artLayers[i];
        if(layer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT){
            changeAntiAlias(layer, "sharp");
        }
   }


alert("Done!");

}

// Run
main();
```